# What is the difference between type [...T] and T when T extends any[] in typescript?

Tags: typescript

Look at the example below, why:

- `values: [...T]` will result `promiseAllTesting1` to have the type of `Promise<[number, number, number]>`
- `values: T` will result `promiseAllTesting2` to have the type of `Promise<number[]>`?

[image]

```js
declare function PromiseAll1<T extends any[]>(
  values: [...T]
): Promise<{
  [K in keyof T]: Awaited<T[K]>;
}>;
const promiseAllTesting1 = PromiseAll1([1, 2, Promise.resolve(3)]);

declare function PromiseAll2<T extends any[]>(
  values: T
): Promise<{
  [K in keyof T]: Awaited<T[K]>;
}>;
const promiseAllTesting2 = PromiseAll2([1, 2, Promise.resolve(3)]);
```

It's from this [type-challenge](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues?q=label%3A20+label%3Aanswer) btw

Comment: I'm pretty sure this behaviour is just an ad-hoc inference rule that enables people to infer tuples without breaking users who rely on PromiseAll2 inferring an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `T` is an [array](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type) or [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type), then the syntax `...T` inside a tuple type is called a **[variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types)**, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094).

Variadic tuple types allow you to concatenate tuples at the type level.  So, for example, if `T` is `[string, number]`, then `[...T, boolean]` is `[string, number, boolean]`.  And `[...T, ...T]` is `[string, number, string, number]`.  And `[...T]` is `[string, number]`.

That means **the type `[...T]` is essentially the same thing as `T`** (although if `T` is a [`readonly` array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) or [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types), then `[...T]` will be a mutable version of it; so `[...readonly [string, number]]` is `[string, number]`.)

---

But if they're basically the same thing, what's the difference between a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function like

```
const f1 = <T extends any[]>(t: T) => t;
```

and one like

```
const f2 = <T extends any[]>(t: [...T]) => t;
```

?  The answer is that they affect *generic type argument inference*.  The `f1` version with just `T` uses normal type inference in the face of arrays.  Normally if you write

```
const a1 = [1, "two", true];
```

then the compiler will infer that `a1` is an unordered array type, not a tuple type:

```
// const a1: (string | number | boolean)[]
```

The same thing happens when you call `f1()`:

```
const x1 = f1([1, "two", true]);
// const x1: (string | number | boolean)[]
```

But for `f2` with `[...T]` gives the compiler a hint that you would like `T` to be a tuple type, so it changes the inference rules a bit to accomplish that:

```
const x2 = f2([1, "two", true]);
// const x2: [number, string, boolean]
```

This behavior is documented in the implementing pull request linked above:

> When the contextual type of an array literal is a tuple type, a tuple type is inferred for the array literal. **The type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types** (emphasis added).

Therefore, if you want array literals to be inferred as unordered arrays, use just `T`, but if you want them to be inferred as tuples, use `[...T]`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAUEkqJLAsinoUUvAPbBQAuSAZgIxIC8SAPACpIIADyYRgAEyhIQwAJ4BtALoA+ABRMAXEn4BKbiqRMA3PmpF6jFiE48F7ADRIAREwDudZ06YAnAK4QSqY0SAD0obQMzDLs2mrMPgCWwADmSAA+xH5gAEYQPhlIOXR0GBCyusrmSNWW0cK2bOxq9k6uHl5G-oG6wTThkVZIDXEJyWmZwNl5BZnFpeXAlUpmIXUsrABM3HyCImKS0rKKqhraCgB0V-xK+lyGJrVRLMLbPFstji7unt7dt30iAN1sNNucprl8k4xqknPMyrIVkQAL5mZFAA)

Comment: The exact answer I'm looking for, thanks boss!

Answer (score 0):

```js
declare function PromiseAll1<T extends any[]>(
  values: [...T] // (1)
): Promise<{
  [K in keyof T]: Awaited<T[K]>;
}>;
```

(1): `T` represents the elements in that array. so if `values` has `length=3` then `T` is a type with array also length is 3 you can learn more about `three dot in javascript`

```js
declare function PromiseAll2<T extends any[]>(
  values: T // (2)
): Promise<{
  [K in keyof T]: Awaited<T[K]>;
}>;
```

(2): T represents the whole array and by default an array has `length` which is dynamic

Comment: That makes sense logically, can you give me a reference link to the Typescript doc for the specific knowledge related to this topic?

Comment: @LoiNguyenHuynh refer to this https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types. this is a scary property of javascript when all `array`, `boolean`, `string`... values ​​are `object`. you can also read more about `dynamic array` and `static array` to understand more about this case

Comment: @jcalz it is document for further reference. the answer was recorded above

Comment: Hmm, the "three dot" here is a TypeScript type operator and looking it up in JavaScript wouldn't help explain it.  Indeed the point of the question seems to be about *variadic tuple types*, but I don't see that mentioned anywhere in the answer.

Comment: I'm not just talking about tuple types; I'm specifically talking about *variadic* tuple types, which involves a different type operator.  See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types

Comment: this is completely inherited from the design principle of `three dot` in javascript if you declare `values: [R, ...T]` then `T` will just be an array of type `values.slice( 1)`

Comment: it can be a bit confusing but in fact we should understand the essence of `three dot` before coming to the detailed explanation

Comment: Let me try a different approach.  How does your explanation account for the behavior [shown in this Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wo8ljw), where `PromiseAll1` and `PromiseAll2` can be seen to behave identically to each other for both input cases?  How does `values` having a length of `3` affect the outcome, and why doesn't the effect differ between the `T` version and the `[...T]` version?  Where does the JavaScript spread operator (what you're calling "three dot") come into play here, given that the code compiles to JavaScript that does not include that operator at all?

Comment: in your example `y` is already typed as an array with `length=3` and `T` represents the array itself so `T` will also be typed with `length=3`

Comment: if you are trying to prove me wrong you must at least show some case where `y` is indeed dynamic and `T` of `PromiseAll2` is of type static array

Comment: Is `x` "dynamic" or "static" in my example?

Comment: `y` in line 20 you set type `y` is array static